# Program feedback: named loop index and reference to constant data

Tags: c++, c, class, coding-style

I had a class assignment that the teacher took off points for a lot of things that I agree with, but a couple of them I'm not so sure about.

*"I am not a fan of naming variables like i, when in fact the counter represents a real thing, a port number:"*

*"It would be better to call it something like portNum, or the like."*

In response to the following lines:

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i <= boat.getLastPort(); ++i){
    boat.load();
    boat.move(i);
    boat.unload();
}
```

**My first question is, is this sound advice, or not even worthwhile?** I rarely see a named loop variable. I thought most people would instantly know what's happening in a situation like this one (in the context of the rest of the program).

---

Second and last feedback:

*"First, method names need to start with lowercase letters, not uppercase. This is a very strong convention in OOP.  But worse, there is no reason to pass in the range value by reference.  The requested value is returned, which is how methods usually work with each other." --- "...No program wants to call a class method and pass in anything by reference:  you would never trust a class with your program variables. Use pass-by-value in methods."*

This quote refers to this member function:

```
int FerryBoat::Rand(const int& range)
{
    return rand() % (range+1);
}
```

The member function was required for the assignment, otherwise I would have just made a macro to do it outside of the class or something. The instructions didn't specify a name so I just named it after the library function, but I guess I should have named it random so it wouldn't have had a capital first letter.

Anyway my second question is: 
 
**If a function takes a reference to const data <sup>(const variable sounds oxymoronic)</sup>, why wouldn't you trust it? Can't it not alter the data because of constness?**

Comment: Passing by const reference saves you a copy, which is important for large objects. For small input-only parameters like `int` and `double` the convention is to pass by value because you gain nothing from passing by reference.

Comment: While I disagree with the teacher about OOP requiring specific convention in general, I still think that it is OK to take points away if programmer deviates from specified conventions. It is really irritating if one programmer on team uses different conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suck it up and move on :-) Even if your teacher is borderline psycho, your job is to pass. Once you're out of school, you can follow your own guidelines if they're better (subject to company rules and regulations of course).

I have to agree with the first sentiment since `boat.move(portNum)` conveys more information then `boat.move(i)`.

Even better would be `boat.moveTo(portNum)` or even `boat.moveToPortNumber(i)`.

Probably not *too* bad if those three lines are all there is but it doesn't cost much to do it "right" even for that small sample. Given how much time people spend maintaining code, the more readable it is, the better.

The second one, I think your teacher has concentrated on the wrong thing. It's not whether it can be corrupted, it's that there's absolutely no point and no advantage to passing an `int` by reference unless you *want* to modify it in the function.

References are good in C++ to avoid the C problems encountered when having to emulate pass-by-reference with pointers and to minimise copying of large structures. In fact, I hope ISO adds them to the next iteration. But, if it's a variable that's cheap to copy (like an `int`) and you don't want to change the variable and have it reflected back to the caller, references are a waste of time.

I very much disagree that method names *need* to start with lower-case letters. While this is a common convention (one I actually use myself), it's *not* a requirement of OOP. The code doesn't suddenly become less object-oriented because your method is called `IsTeacherLoony()` rather than `isTeacherLoony()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I guess most of those two things I posted that he said were worthwhile. To give him some credit there was a lot of other feedback on that assignment that I didn't feel the need to ask about. The main function was pretty much just that loop exactly as I posted it with one other thing before the return. I never realized until today that the size of a reference to native int is exactly the same size. I've just been passing by reference to const by default unless I needed to alter the passed variable or its copy.